# Disable a Azure API Managment policy in the operation scope which is set in the product scope

Tags: azure-api-management

I am currently working with Azure API managemnet where I am stuck at a wired junction. My client wants Product level authentication, so I have created one product and added a  policy there. But, now for an particular api the it is not required.

I tried a lot of thing like, deleteing the authorization header but it is not working. can you please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: from the description I understand that you have created a product and added a policy at product scope, and you need that policy not to be executed for an particular operation of an api correct me if am wrong here

Comment: Yes, you understood my concern correctly. Do you have come across such a situation?  Please let me know if you have a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the base tag in the inbound section of the policy for that operation by doing that the policy applied at product level will not be executed for the particular operation.

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-policies

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. it was so naive of me.